# Newton's way of getting a Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion, math-history

I don't understand how Newton find the Taylor expansion of $\frac{a^2}{b+x}$ by the following method :

[image: Newton's Method]

**This screenshot is from : [The method of fluxions and infinite series](https://archive.org/stream/methodoffluxions00newt#page/3/mode/1up)

Any idea ?

Comment: ...and this is yet another reason why to read originals of old mathematicians' works can be pretty annoying and frustrating: their notation, among other things, is close to impossible to understand **if** we don't first learn what they meant. My advice is to try to get a version of the original but with (1) modern notation, and (2) explaining notes of what the author meant in some steps, what he knew, what he didn't, etc. Interesting question. +1

Comment: He is dividing $a^2$ by $b+x$ using long division, and his method is the same as the one we use today, except he is putting the quotient to the right of the $a^2$ instead of on top of it, as we do now.

Comment: This is just high-school long division where you write the terms in ascending degree instead of descending. It works very nicely for dividing any power series into another.

Comment: [The fraction ... being propofed](http://hotmeme.net/media/mememaker/9/6/2342-phteven.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}&aa\;&\mid& b+x\\&aa+\frac{aa}bx&\mid&\frac{aa}b\\
&------&--&----------\\
&0-\frac{aa}bx&\mid&\frac{aa}b-\frac{aax}{b^2}\\
&\;\;-\frac{aa}bx-\frac{aax^2}{b^2}&\mid&\\&------&--&----------\\&\frac{aax^2}{b^2}&\mid& \end{align}$$

and etc.

he thus gets

$$\frac{aa}{b+x}=\frac{aa}b-\frac{aax}{b^2}+\frac{aax^2}{b^3}-\ldots$$